# Deep zoom Tile generation of very large size image

Tags: zooming, deepzoom, openseadragon

I need to generate deep zoom tiles for an image of size 50,000 x 50,000 pixels. I tried using deep zoom composer software but it keeps loading the file without any success.
Please help me how can i generate deep zoom tiles for such large image. Thanks

Comment: I found Vips as a very good solution for it. https://libvips.blogspot.com/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of tools you can use:

http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/creating-zooming-images/

For large images I'm a fan of VIPS:

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html

Comment: Github links are broken.

Comment: @Qumber thank you for the heads-up! I have now fixed them :)